# Passing dynamic argument on onClick inside for does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following react code does not work.'select' function is always called with 10 instead of assigned values.

```
    select( x ) {
      alert( x ); // Always alerts 10.
    }

    render() {
      var AllData = [];
      for( var i = 0; i<10 ;i++ ) {
        AllData.push( 
          <div key={i} onClick={() => this.select(i)} >{i}</div>
        );
      }   
      return (
        <div>
          {AllData}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

How do I pass dynamic value in for loop correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using ES2015 *arrow function* notation, I'd suggest to just replace `var` by `let` for your loop variable initialization. That way you have a true *block scope*, otherwise you have to deal with *function scope* which is the root of your trouble here.

```
for( let i = 0; i<10 ;i++ ) {
   AllData.push( 
       <div key={i} onClick={() => this.select(i)} >{i}</div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a new scope for the `i` variable, so it doesn't use the same for them all. One way you could achieve it is by using an immediately function:

```
select( x ) {
  alert( x );
}

render() {
  var AllData = [];
  for( var i = 0; i<10 ;i++ ) {
    ((i) => {
        AllData.push( 
          <div key={i} onClick={() => this.select(i)} >{i}</div>
        );      
    })(i);
  }   
  return (
    <div>
      {AllData}
    </div>
  );
}
```